# Partition Flash Drive?

Tags: 11.10, partitioning, usb-drive, live-usb

I want to partition a USB flash drive so that two gigabytes is reserved for ubuntu and persistence, and the other two is for my files. I used `gparted` to create two fat32 partitions on the flash drive. Natulius show the two partitions, good. However, when I open the Starup Disk Creator, it shows the flash drive as one drive instead of two partitions. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and a 4gb flash drive. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried first installing with Startup Disk Creator using the whole drive, then coming back and making the second partition?

Comment: Did you solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use disk utility to make partitions (primary and logical)
then use the startup disk creator usb

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that, you probably better use "unetbootin" instead to create a bootable live flash drive.